# PHP adding to cart

Tags: php

ATM, I'm testing my cart. When I load a new page with products to add to cart, they add add fine but i also get an error of for example:

Notice: Undefined index: cart_25 in

25 IS the index that is associated with the product.

```
  if (isset($_GET['add'])) {
   $_SESSION['cart_'.(int)$_GET['add']]+=1;
   }


   foreach($_SESSION as $name => $value) {
    if ($value>0){
     if (substr($name,0,5)=='cart_') {
       $name = substr($name, 5, (strlen($name)-5));
       echo $name.'<br />';
     }
```

Any tips to help would be great

Comment: As one of the answers below indicates, there's no need to cast the $_GET['add'] to an int, when you are going to concatenate it (as a string) to 'cart_'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try it this way:

```
$key = 'cart_' . $_GET['add'];
$_SESSION[$key] = isset($_SESSION[$key]) ? $_SESSION[$key] + 1 : 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `cart_{index}` why don't you just make the array multiple dimensions?  Then your `foreach` loop would be a lot simpler.  You may also want to have functions or methods for adding and removing items so you don't have to do the same tests every time.

```
function add_to_cart($index, $amount) {
   if (!isset($_SESSION['cart'][$index])) {
      $_SESSION['cart'][$index] = 0;
   }
   $_SESSION['cart'][$index] += $amount;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$_SESSION['cart_'.(int)$_GET['add']]+=1;` does `$_SESSION['cart_'.(int)$_GET['add']] = **$_SESSION['cart_'.(int)$_GET['add']]** + 1;`
so first time it will be undefined, so

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['cart_'.(int)$_GET['add']])) {
    $_SESSION['cart_'.(int)$_GET['add'] = 1;
} else {
    $_SESSION['cart_'.(int)$_GET['add']]+=1;
}
```